# Javascript code for showing yesterday's date and todays date

Tags: javascript, date

How to show yesterday's date in my  textbox the yesterday's date and at the same time, the today's date in ?

I have this home.php where I show the date yesterday(user cannot modify this-readonly) and the date today(user MUST input the date today). And when tomorrow comes and the user visits the home .php s/he will saw the date inputted yesterday, and will input the date again for romorrow's.

E.G: Day1 (march 30, 2011)
Yesterday's date: March 29, 2011. (Not editable textbox) 
Enter date today: (I'll type..) March 30, 2011.

Day 2 (march 31, 2011)
Yesterday's date: March 30, 2011. (Not editable textbox) Automatically, this will appear upon hitting the home.php
Enter date today: (I'll type..) March 31, 2011.

and so on..

I need a validation that wont accept wrong date format and the format must be: 01-Mar-11
How to do this? :(

Comment: if user can enter only todays date, why is it editable?? why dont you put it there by yourself??

Comment: Hi Furgan, I have no prob with entering today's date. My prob is that I can't get the yesterday's date. :(

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Yesterday's date is simply today's date less one, so:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
```

If today is 1 April, then it is set to 0 April which is converted to 31 March.

Since you also wanted to do some other stuff, here are some functions to do it:

```
// Check if d is a valid date
// Must be format year-month name-date
// e.g. 2011-MAR-12 or 2011-March-6
// Capitalisation is not important
function validDate(d) {
  var bits = d.split('-');
  var t = stringToDate(d);
  return t.getFullYear() == bits[0] && 
         t.getDate() == bits[2];
}

// Convert string in format above to a date object
function stringToDate(s) {
  var bits = s.split('-');
  var monthNum = monthNameToNumber(bits[1]);
  return new Date(bits[0], monthNum, bits[2]);
}

// Convert month names like mar or march to 
// number, capitalisation not important
// Month number is calendar month - 1.
var monthNameToNumber = (function() {
  var monthNames = (
     'jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec ' +
     'january february march april may june july august ' +
     'september october november december'
     ).split(' ');

  return function(month) {
    var i = monthNames.length;
    month = month.toLowerCase(); 

    while (i--) {
      if (monthNames[i] == month) {
        return i % 12;
      }
    }
  }
}());

// Given a date in above format, return
// previous day as a date object
function getYesterday(d) {
  d = stringToDate(d);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1)
  return d;
}

// Given a date object, format
// per format above
var formatDate = (function() {
  var months = 'jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec'.split(' ');
  function addZ(n) {
    return n<10? '0'+n : ''+n;
  }
  return function(d) {
    return d.getFullYear() + '-' + 
           months[d.getMonth()] + '-' + 
           addZ(d.getDate());
  }
}());

function doStuff(d) {

  // Is it format year-month-date?
  if (!validDate(d)) {
    alert(d + ' is not a valid date');
    return;
  } else {
    alert(d + ' is a valid date');
  }
  alert(
    'Date in was: ' + d +
    '\nDay before: ' + formatDate(getYesterday(d))
  );
}


doStuff('2011-feb-08');
// Shows 2011-feb-08 is a valid date
//       Date in was: 2011-feb-08
//       Day before: 2011-feb-07
```

Answer (score 73):

One liner:

```
var yesterday = new Date(Date.now() - 864e5); // 864e5 == 86400000 == 24*60*60*1000
```

Comment: Might worth using `8640000` rather than doing the calculation `24*60*60*1000` each time.

Comment: It should be `86400000`

Comment: @danielcorin you're right. I just wanted the answer to be clear. I'll update the answer. 
`24*60*60*1000 ==> 86400000 ==> 864e5`

Comment: Actually, this type of micro optimization gains pretty much nothing in terms of performance and hurts readability, I always use `24*60*60*1000` instead.

Comment: I'd like to use this to get tomorrow as well. I've added + instead of minus, but it plays funny when it gests to 2020-12-31 - basically it doesn't get tomorrow when at the end of the year but it works for every other date. Any idea why?

Comment: @Nick what do you mean it plays funny?
i tried the following on console and it works well: `new Date(Date.now() + 86400000)` and `new Date(new Date('2020-12-31T00:00:00Z').getTime() + 86400000)`
some common pitfalls: timezones, mixing Date object / epoch time in seconds / epoch time in milliseconds / iso time string

Answer (score 8):

Yesterday's date can be calculated as,

```
var prev_date = new Date();
prev_date.setDate(prev_date.getDate() - 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Get yesterday date in javascript**

You have to run code and check it output

```js
    var today = new Date();
    var yesterday = new Date(today);
    
    yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
    console.log("Original Date : ",yesterday);

    const monthNames = [
  "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
];
    var month = today.getMonth() + 1
    yesterday = yesterday.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[month] + ' ' + yesterday.getFullYear()
   
    console.log("Modify Date : ",yesterday);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday Date can be calculated as:-

```
let now = new Date();
var defaultDate = now - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1;
defaultDate = new Date(defaultDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone need one-line code than this is also correct

```
const yesterday = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1));
```

happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I developed a simple and efficient function to return previous date. The function takes in getTime() value and return the integer that could be passed to create a new date object. Below is the code:

```js
function getPrevDate(val: number): number {
  const aDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  const last = new Date().getTime() - val * aDay;
  return last;
}

const last = getPrevDate(5);

console.log(new Date(last), new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct one-liner / can be used in-place, similar to where you `new Date()` :

```
new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1))
```