# Decrement the date by one day using javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   var date = new Date();
   var data_new = [];var url ='http://www.domain.com /kjdshlka/api.php?date=2014-07-15'; 
   $.getJSON(url,function(result) { 
     var elt = [date,result.requests];data_new.push(elt);console.log(data_new);
   });
});
```

I am struggling to decrement the date by one day using javascript for loop.Here is my code,from the url im getting some requests.like if i decrease the date by one day other requests will come .Now i need this process for 7days using javascript for loop.Can anybody please tel me how to do ?

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript code for showing yesterday's date and todays date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495815/javascript-code-for-showing-yesterdays-date-and-todays-date)

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date(); // Date you want, here I got the current date and time
date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
```

getDate() will give you the date, then reduce it by 1 and using setDate() you can replace date again.

Answer (score 1):

var today = new Date();

var yesterday = new Date(today.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); //(hours * minutes * seconds * milliseconds)

console.log(yesterday);

Comment: Hi fezzy , thanks for your reply .But i need to decrease the date by one day for one week . for that i need for loop fezzy .

Answer (score 0):

```
 var now = new Date();
 console.log(now);

 var yesterday = new Date(now - 86400000);
 console.log(yesterday);

 /* In a Decrement Loop*/
 for(var i=100;i>0;i--){
    console.log(new Date(now - i*86400000));
 }
```