# display 270 days prior to the current date in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am trying to load date which is 270 prior from today. I tried the following code but looks like something is wrong.

```
var d = new Date();
alert(d.setDate(d.getDate() - 2).toString()); //2 is just that I tried some number
```

I want to display that in the following format too dd/mm/yyyy.
Thanks

Comment: If you need to do a lot of date stuff, I recommend using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com). It makes this sort of thing much easier (`moment().subtract(270, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY')` in your case).

Comment: Also answered here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495815/javascript-code-for-showing-yesterdays-date-and-todays-date/5495838

Comment: Rayon's code is working really nice. But I would like to try MomentJs as well. I will try that out and let you know. Thanks @GregL

Comment: @GregL Thanks for letting me know the wonderful moment magic :-) It is really much easier as you said.

Comment: @GregL Can that be used even for date validations ?

Answer (score 6):

> `DATEOBJ.getDate` will return you date
>
> `DATEOBJ.getMonth` will return month(0-11)
>
> `DATEOBJ.getFullYear` will return year(yyyy *4 digits*)

```js
function pad(n) {
  return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
}
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 270);
alert(d);
alert(pad(d.getDate()) + '/' + pad(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear());
```

Comment: This won't _quite_ satisfy the `dd/mm/yyyy` requirement, because the day and month won't have leading zeroes if < 10, which the `dd` and `mm` bit usually indicate. But that is pretty easily solved with a helper function.

Comment: @GregL, I just ignored that. Have updated my answer!